# Provide a way to retrieve questions and answers that have been deleted

Tags: feature-request, api, api-v2.2, posts

Could you please provide a way to retrieve deleted questions/answers?

Your database contains that data, until you hard delete it, so it would be useful for us to have the chance to play with it.

I'm suggesting to add a parameter like:

```
deleted (optional)

    * When "true", will include deleted id where available.
    * boolean
```

Why I'm asking it?
Well, because a lot of questions were [recently deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/74909/what-happened-to-what-real-life-bad-habits-has-programming-given-you) and it would be cool to have access to them without using the [data dumps](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/).

Comment: +1 - That would be quite useful indeed, but I wouldn't hold my breath ... It seems about time to expose these dumps regularly elsewhere for this and similar needs, i.e. something along the lines of the most excellent [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) (including the ability to persist queries and/or a respective API), but with access to historical dumps as well.

Comment: Note this went from [status-planned] to no status, just a few minutes ago. But, *not* officially declined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This goes hand in hand with authentication.

Comment: And updates on this feature?

Comment: And again, is this live and just undocumented or dead?

Comment: Not always hand in hand [some little bug in middle](http://stackapps.com/questions/6955/why-is-questions-api-returning-deleted-questions)

Comment: Couple of years later, any updates on this? Is it still status-planned? Returning deleted questions from the API would be very convenient to easily track deletion events (either manual deletion by delete votes or those from the roomba by Community).