# How to get deleted answers?

Tags: discussion, api, answers

Users with a certain reputation, can see deleted answers (deleted either by moderators or by their owners themselves).

Does the API offer any means to access such deleted answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is nearly a duplicate of: *[Provide a way to retrieve questions and answers that have been deleted](https://stackapps.com/questions/1917/provide-a-way-to-retrieve-questions-and-answers-that-have-been-deleted)* -- which has been "status planned" for 6+ years.

In general, it is very hard to search for answers in the API; everything's geared towards questions -- especially the `/search` and `/search/advanced`.

There is no way to search for deleted answers, even ones you have permission to see.
For example, **[stackoverflow.com/search?q=is:answer deleted:yes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer%20deleted%3Ayes) tells me I have 165 deleted answers** and, also:

> Note: only content you own is returned when searching for deleted content

But when I try the API:
          [/2.2/search/advanced?q=is:answer deleted:yes](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#q=is%3Aanswer%20deleted%3Ayes&filter=!0Usmbwl8HHm8mlqAFm7Dgnzkx&site=stackoverflow&run=true) (with an appropriate filter set)

It gives me 14,884,687 *questions* (that's all of them) irregardless of whether I have an answer to the Q or not.

And, when I use `/questions/{ids}/answers` to search a question where I know I have a deleted answer, the results only show me the undeleted answers. (Note that I exceed 10K rep on that site and can see any deleted content that I stumble across.)

Finally [the answer object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/answer) does not have any sort of property like `deleted`, `deletion_date`, etc.   So, clearly, the current API was not meant to support deleted answers.

Comment: Note to self:  Should retest some day using API 2.3 and an access_token.